# Stop QLPreviewController from resizing in presented View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm presenting a NavigationViewController in iPad app as formSheet, which works great. But in this presented NavigationViewController when I push QLPreviewController with one Image to display  it resizes it self to fit the Image. This alone would not have been a problem but upon going back to previous viewController form QLPreviewController the resized viewController size affect all ViewControllers in that NavgationViewController.

If there is any way to go back to default size for viewController on coming back from QLPreviewController it would help too. Or If QLPreviewController doesn't resize when pushed.

Also this problem is only in iOS 13+.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolved it on my own.

Create one Variable

```
var defaultPreferredContentSize: CGSize?
```

and one method

```
fileprivate func adjustViewControllerSizeIfNeeded() {
    if let size = defaultPreferredContentSize {
        if self.navigationController?.preferredContentSize != size {
            self.navigationController?.preferredContentSize = size
        }
    } else {
        defaultPreferredContentSize = self.view.frame.size
    }
}
```

Call this method in viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    adjustViewControllerSizeIfNeeded()
}
```